# How to convert UTF-8 to GBK string in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I retrieved HTML string from an objective site and within it there is a section

```
class="f9t" name="ÓÃ»§Ãû:ôâÈ»12"
```

I know it's in GBK encoding, as I can see it from the FF browser display. But I do not know how to convert that name string into a readable GBK string (such as 上海 or 北京).

I am using

```
String sname = new String(name.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
byte[] gbkbytes = sname.getBytes("gb2312");
String gbkStr = new String( gbkbytes );
System.out.println(gbkStr);
```

but it's not printed right in GBK text

```
???¡ì??:????12
```

I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Almost always when you get garbage characters like `ÓÃ»§Ãû:ôâÈ»12` it means that the data were misinterpreted as Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1, not UTF-8.

Comment: I did an experiment: `new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "GBK")`
yielded `用户名:翕然12`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this if you already read the name with a wrong encoding and get the wrong name value "ÓÃ»§Ãû:ôâÈ»12", as @Karol S suggested:

```
new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "GBK")
```

Or if you read a GBK or GB2312 string from internet or a file, use something like this to get the right string at the first place:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"GBK")); name = r.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `name.getBytes()` returns GBK encoded string it's enough to create string specifying encoding of array of bytes:

```
new String(gbkString.getBytes(), "GBK");
```

Regarding to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) the name of encryption should be `GBK`.

Sample code:

```
String gbkString = "ÓÃ»§Ãû:ôâÈ»12";
String utfString = new String(gbkString.getBytes(), "GBK");
System.out.println(utfString);
```

Result (not 100% sure that it's correct :) ):
脫脙禄搂脙没:么芒脠禄12

Comment: No... the output string does not look right. the web page says 'content="text/html; charset=gbk"' and some applications such as FF or notepad++ can understand how to decode it and display it, but i have no clue.    Thank you though.

Comment: Could you provide link to the web page? Then I would know what does server returns as byte stream.